# Selenium hangs from firefox. (?)

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium

I'm having this problem with both selenium 3.40 and 3.39 (I don't know what about previous versions).

After a time period that selenium is running (and executing) my test stuck and fail on "find element" and throws the following exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote
>   WebDriver server for URL
>   `http://localhost:7055/hub/session/44f53200-6259-4f38-8738-b4beda40429f/elements`
>   timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   operation has timed out    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
>   at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElements(String mechanism,
>   String value)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementsByXPath(String
>   xpath)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(ISearchContext
>   context)    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElements(ISearchContext context)
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElements(By by)

This issue is a matter of how long selenium is running: When running a test alone, it does not happen. But when I run a test as a part of many tests, it happens.

A call that comes after a one which fails can succeed.

Happen also with chrome.
I tried going back so Selenium 2.34 and the problem still exist.

Comment: I bet this is because your `WebDriver` object is `static`.  can you confirm?

Comment: Yes!, it is under single tone, why?! (I'm not using threads / parallel calls)

Comment: The WebDriver itself is not a single tone, but it is under another class (that envelopes it) which is a single tone, which other components uses in order to access the WebDriver.

Comment: I would just say to be aware of what version of Selenium you are running as compared to exactly what Firefox browser version is installed on your system.   Also, get the latest 2.9 Chrome binary and try your test with Chrome to see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it:
I set

```
WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

somewhere in my code, this causes every element lookup to wait for 60 seconds for the element to appear.

Answer (score 1):

According to your confirmation, I can say that you are getting this issue because your `WebDriver` object is `static`.  You can run your tests fine one by one, but once you try to run multiple at a time, the JVM considers your different tests to have the same `WebDriver` object!  Funny, huh..

Find a way to remove the `static` modifier from your object, which will most likely require you to change your entire structure, and it **WILL** fix your issue.

Source:

> An experienced user of Selenium who's had this issue before trying to run multiple tests, and recieved the same sort of behavior, and fixed it by following the steps above.

Comment: No, this is not the issue: I'm not running tests in parallel. I did try to remove the static modifier (just in case), but it did help.